# Automatically call a function when inside a certain module/controller

Tags: laravel-4

Is it possible to call a function in a certain module every request?

Let say I have module name called 'configuration', on this module, I have a list of controllers and list of functions/methods. What I want is to automatically pass my "Menu" to the View without manually passing it on each methods and controllers.

This menu is only available when inside the 'configuration module.

```
// I have extended the base controller to create common functions
ConfigureController extends \BaseController
{
    protected function processMenu() {
    }
}


// One of my controller that needs to render processMenu()
SetupController extends ConfigureController 
{
    public index() 
    {
        // I want to optimize this portion so that I do not have to call it evertime
        $pass_to_view = $this->processMenu();

        // I need to pass it again and again
        return View::make('setup')->with('data', $pass_to_view );

    }
}
```

PS. sample code only

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use the BaseController constructor __construct() and within the SetupController's constructor call parent::__construct();

Comment: jeez forgot the constructor method. I am thinking way to much that this feature is inside Laravel. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ill add as answer @Paengski

Answer (score 1):

Use the BaseController constructor method __construct() and within the SetupController's constructor call parent::__construct();

Answer (score 0):

This is where the view composers come handy.
Put your menu in a partial, include it in you layout, then register a view composer (doc here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers).

You can put your register code anywhere, for instance you could create a file composers.php in app and include it in your app/start/global.php.